# How to put div tag to put all buttons on one line?

Tags: css, reactjs, bulma

[image: FilterButton]

*Code for Filter Button*

```js
import React from "react";

function FilterButton(props){
    return (   
        <div className="box">    
        <button 
            type = "submit"
            className="button is-info"
            onClick={()=>props.setFilter(props.name)}
        >
            <span>{props.name}</span>   
        </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FilterButton;
```

Unfortunately, the `div` tag is not able to put the following buttons(*All*, *Active*, *Completed*, *Important*) on the same line.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: There is plenty way of doing it. Do you want to use plain css, or are you using a framework in your project, like Bootstrap for example ?

Comment: @TheTisiboth,  I am using BULMA framework in my project. thank you for your interest and help in my project.

Comment: You probably need to replace className="box" or edit .box in the css.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the grid system of BULMA, you can do the following things:
see https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    First column
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Second column
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Third column
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Fourth column
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use css in order to do this, you can use the css property `display: inline-block`,as it is shown here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp